# Django Upload directory with subdirectories

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to upload directory along with subdirectories using django  , i have searched alot but could not find any solution. any method to do so ?

Comment: Have you considered uploading a compressed archive that might contain subdirectories? It's fairly easy to traverse an archive such as a .zip file, and it greatly simplifies the upload process.

Comment: thanks brandon , you mean creating zip file using javascript and then upload it ?

Comment: Rather, create the archive ahead of time.

Comment: its not possible , because i want to give user the option to upload folder

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible to select a directory with a file input